# Angular.js MySQL JSON to $scope

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs, electron

I have a problem with getting data from MySQL database to angular $scope.

Here is my **app.js**

```
var mxscope = angular.module('mxscope', ['ui.router']);

mxscope.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

$stateProvider    
    .state('stock', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'views/stock.html',
        controller: 'stockController'
    })

});

mxscope.controller('stockController', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get('lib/getStockProducts.php')

    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.products = data;
    })
    .error(function(){
        console.log('error whatever');
    })
});
```

If You look on the particular controllers there is one with http.get request
And it doesn't seem to work: but I've found some strange behavior when testing it. The whole app is wrapped into .Electron app, and when I try the app the http.get request returns the code inside .php file.. Like so:

**getStockProducts.php**

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$query="select * from sc_products";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

$arr = array();

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
}
echo $json_response = json_encode($arr);
?>
```

with an dupes error :

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=product%20in%20products&p1=string%3Ap&p2=p

But when I fire up the same app in browser window it works like charm, but it still returns duplicate result.

Any help ?

Comment: Can you expose the code of the $http request and, most important, you need to track down where your server side code is sending back his own code.

Comment: I didn't understand anything You have just said. Expose the http request ? It's in the code snippet i pasted above. And where server code ought to send code ? the php file returns raw  JSON string. The Http request either gets it or not. It should work according to Angular docs.

Comment: You need to provide more code. Your error seems to be on the server side.

Comment: https://github.com/marffinn/SCOPE   that is the whole project file